# Yellow Tint on existing BMP Image

Tags: c, colors, bmp, tint

Using C language, I use this code to tint to grayscale:

```
    // Compute grayscale value using the formula
    int grayscale = (int)(0.299 * img->pArr[i][j].red +
                      0.587 * img->pArr[i][j].green +
                      0.114 * img->pArr[i][j].blue);
    
    // Set the same grayscale value for each RGB component
    img->pArr[i][j].red = grayscale;
    img->pArr[i][j].green = grayscale;
    img->pArr[i][j].blue = grayscale;
```

What values should I use to compute a yellow scale for the image?

thanks

I have tried different combinations of decimals with no luck.

Comment: Yellow is n * R, n * G, 0 * B

Comment: Yellow is n * R, n * G, 0 * B
Is the 'n' the same number for both R and G.

Comment: any value I use it creates a gray or blueish tint